# How can I attach existing multiple Iam roles with one policy using list(string) terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have trying to attach one Iam policy to with multiple existing Iam Role , role already is there so used data , and inside the variable mention all existing Iam role names using with list(string),
and the main file added role as a  data and another new resource for attachment ,
I have listed my code below, its getting  error like `invalid expression value : a number is require`

I think I am not used correctly for  resource attachment at correct manner, because all role name it should be taken from variable as list(string) one by one .
Can one help me to correct this issue, Thanks.

**vars.tf**

```
variable "aws_iam_roles" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = ["role1", "role2", "role3"]
}
```

**main.tf**

```
data "aws_iam_roles" "role-policy-attachment" {
  count      = "length(var.aws_iam_roles)"
  role       = "var.aws_iam_roles[count.index]"
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.policy.arn
}



resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "data-role" {
role = data.aws_iam_role.custom.id
policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.policy.arn
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues here which can all be solved with the following:

```
data "aws_iam_role" "role-policy-attachment" {
  for_each = toset(var.aws_iam_roles)

  name = each.value
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "data-role" {
  for_each = data.aws_iam_role.role-policy-attachment

  role       = each.value.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.policy.arn
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The length function should not be put in quotes. This should fix the issue with count.

```
data "aws_iam_roles" "role-policy-attachment" {
  count      = length(var.aws_iam_roles)
  role       = "var.aws_iam_roles[count.index]"
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.policy.arn
}
```

However, you also need to use count or for loop for aws_iam_role_policy_attachment. Because each role requires a separate attachment to be made.

Comment: I getting error related to  count - length(var.aws_iam_roles) , invalid expression value a number required

Comment: What is your terraform version?

Comment: In case you have a much older version, the above expression may not work. You can try this for older versions:  “${length(var.aws_iam_roles)}”

Comment: I have tried with 1.0.0 as well, but getting same

Comment: Can you please give both like attachment and data source , because for me its not working